# SQL Query with Long Date Time?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I am trying to pass a SQL query through c# , currently it is based on just the day month and year with time always set to 0 EG 1997-10-28 00.00.00.000 which is great as the time never changes it easy for me to just Select Where date equals the calendar date.

However with the Start Field , the time is different on each record , eg 1899-12-30 14.14:00.00.000 , 1899-12-30 15.14:30.00.000 . (Seconds downwards are always the same) .

So I need to have a query that will return all the results of the selected date on the "Start" field . How would I do this?.

E.G IF i click the calendar which passes 1997-10-28 00.00.00.000 , I would like the results of every time in that day!. How do I go about that?.

Thanks for any input.

EDIT: Is there a way to format the date that i have in SQL ?. This comes from an old access database!. and as you can see above it is 1899-12-30 ?. not 1998 , I don't know why this has happened!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, your_start_field, @your_param) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to select all record between today and tomorrow without including tomorrow's date.

```
WHERE EventDate >= StartDate AND EventDate < DATEADD(d, 1, StartDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just query the date part. I think this should work...

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE StartDate = '1997-10-28'
```

EDIT: Above may not work but following should cover needs

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE StartDate >= '1997-10-28 00:00:00.000' AND StartDate < '1997-10-29 00:00:00.000'
```

(notice the second date is the following date)

Comment: StartDate includes the time portion of the date so it wouldn't work.

Comment: yes that would now work.  You could however do `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE StartDate between '1997-10-28 00:00:00.000' and '1997-10-28 23:59:59.997'`

Comment: @Bob Vale, I had thought of the 23.59... but I though my suggestion would prove easier to get the second date value in code.. FirstDate.AddDays(1);

Comment: The advantage of the between queries is that some databases have been known not to index properly on the >= and < queries yet quite happily use indexes for between. Its rare but it has happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL `DATEADD(d,datediff(d,0,startdate),startdate)` will convert a date with time to just the date;

eg

```
Select field1,field2 from mytable where DATEADD(d,datediff(d,0,startdate),startdate)='1997-10-28'
```